# "Connection is not associated with a managed connection" After changing MySQL's JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jboss6.x

I have a webapp running on jboos 6.0.1.

After changing  MySQL's JDBC Driver from 5.1.10 to 5.1.33 i'm getting  sometimes the following Exception :

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Cannot open connection
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:148) [:0.0.2]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:227) [:0.0.2]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353) [:0.0.2]
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209) [:0.0.2]
            .
            .
            .
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is not associated with a managed connection.org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@1841c24c
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:90)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.lock(WrappedStatement.java:64)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setClob(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:802)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$2$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$1$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(Basic
```

It seems that a modification made in the driver between the versions 5.1.13 and 5.1.14 caused the problem. ( it is may be and old bug that didn't happens because the driver was permessive =)

Comment: I think it depends upon the jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

I used this JVM parameters -Dhibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true and it Works now !